# What is the value of x5 at the end of the execution of this instruction?

Tags: assembly, riscv

```
addi x5,x0,1
addi x6,x0,5`
loop:
blt x6,x0,EXIT
addi x6,x6,-1
slli x5,x5,1
jal x0,loop
exit
```

assuming x5=0, x6=0, i'd like to understand why after the execution x5=64.

Comment: Here's an idea: you can answer this for yourself, by entering that code into a simulator and run it.  If you like you can even single step to see each instruction do its thing.  Looks like it will take about 20 instructions to reach completion.  Try [RARS](https://github.com/TheThirdOne/rars) if you don't already have one.

Comment: Looks like it's doing `1<<6` one shift-count at a time.  As Erik says, single-step it in a simulator and watch register values change, if you can't see it in your head.  Also, you don't need to assume anything about the initial value of registers; they're each written unconditionally by `addi`.  The inputs to those addi instructions are the zero-register (hard-wired to `0`) and an immediate.  i.e. `x5 = 0 + 1`, making the previous value irrelevant.

Comment: thank you so much guys but i can't use a simulator, that's why i need to understand the logic behind it

Comment: Well, I guess before you can run it on the simulator, you first need to understand what each instruction does. Here is the riscv cheat sheet for that. https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1617/ECAD+Arch/files/docs/RISCVGreenCardv8-20151013.pdf
Then there is a bit of catch here, x0 in riscv is zero register, which means it always reads as zero and writes to it are ignored.

Comment: Another thing is, `i` in the end of (most of the) instructions denotes immediate. it means there is an immediate value provided which must be used in the operation. For example: addi x5, x0, 1. Here 1 is an immediate value. This instruction simply adds x0 and 1 and stores it in x5.

Comment: ok thanks but in this case?

Comment: The point of using a simulator is to single-step and watch registers change, in order to understand the logic.  If you don't have a usable simulator installed or available online, that's your first problem to fix before you ask other people to explain things you could see for yourself with a simulator.  (online, google found https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2019sp/riscv/interpreter/ and also https://opensourcelibs.com/lib/kvakil-venus / https://www.kvakil.me/venus/.  Or to install locally, there are even more options, including RARS is good for beginners.)

Answer (score 3):

Basically what the code does is decrement register x6 by 1, and double register x5 (x5 = 2, x5 = 4, x5 = 8, x5 = 16, x5 = 32, x5 = 64) because it starts at 1, and is shifted to the left 6 times (because x6 has the value 5).

I also commented the code for a better understanding.

```
  addi x5,x0,1           # load value 1 into register x5 you can also use "li, x5, 1" is the same as addi x5,x0,1
  addi x6,x0,5           # load value 5 into register x6
loop:                  # label to be able to return from the jal instruction
  blt x6,x0, exit        # if register x6<0 end the program else continue 
  addi x6,x6,-1          # subtract a 1 from the x6 register
  slli x5,x5,1           # shift left 1 ("001", "010", "100")
  jal x0,loop            # jump to the address of the loop tag
exit:                  # here it jumps when it is satisfied that x6 <0
```

I recommend you see some of the reference cards for risc-v and be able to understand each of the instructions.